# Error in Fitting a Keras Model

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I am having the problem with the following python code which uses the library keras, and I have not been able to find a solution online:

```
       def model_build():
        model_mag=Sequential()
        model_mag.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', input_dim=5))  
        model_mag.add(Dropout(0.5))
        model_mag.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
        model_mag.add(Dropout(0.5))
        model_mag.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
        model_mag.add(Dense(1))
        model_mag.compile(loss=losses.mean_squared_error,optimizer='sgd')
        return model_mag
       clf = KerasRegressor(build_fn=model_build(),nb_epoch=100)
       # here is the error
       clf.fit(X_train,y_train, nb_epoch=20)
```

I know that X_train and y_train are well defined above and I can run other classifier methods just fine with them so they are not the problem. It keeps throwing me the following error and I can't figure out why:

TypeError: **call**() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

I am giving two arguments though.

Comment: Can you add python and keras versions?

Comment: python version 2.7.13, keras version 2.0.4

Comment: I would rather try in https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ which is more active around Keras

Comment: @SheelStueber What is the line raising the error?

Comment: It is the clf.fit line that is throwing the error. Is there a way to move this to datascience?

Comment: Maybe just repost it, @SheelStueber

Comment: Try omitting the nb_epoch param?

Comment: I messed around with a bunch of the parameters, such as adding and deleting more parameters, but I am still thrown the same error